# matplotlib plot figure hiden on background on macosx

Tags: matplotlib

When drawing with matplotlib from terminal on macosx, everything works fine but if I clicked other with, then the ploted figure will be in the background. if other window is maximum screen, then I never had a chance to get the matplotlib figure back unless I hide all other windows then will find it.

I try to find it from window menu but nothing there! sounds like the plot (launched from terminal) is not a window at all.

What's the easiest way to bring my figure back to top if I needed? It's really annoy to hide other window to find the figure!

Comment: what backend are you using?

Comment: I just use it by default. I install everything from anaconda.